# How to properly insert text into a kernel's video memory?

Tags: c, keyboard-events, osdev

I know this the title is weird (I don't know how to explain it :| ) but bear with me.

I am making an OS in `assembly` and `C`.  I have made a kernel and have text input and output.

I am having issues with printing or adding a space bar event; if I print a `' '` (space char) it will just override the next character (Like when we have the insert key pressed in a text editor and if we move the cursor behind a character `a|bc`and type a char ex.`b` so it becomes `b|bc` ).
I want it to insert the char between the chars and move the chars forward `abbc` like normally.  How do I do that in C in 32-bit protected mode?

the printing method to the screen

```
    location = video_memory + (cursor_y*80 + cursor_x); //video memory is the start of the buffer 
    *location = c | attribute; //location is the calculated location to put the char in the buffer and c is the char 
    cursor_x++;
```

this overwrites the next char

Comment: Suggestion: I think you should change the title from *OS- How to properly print a spacebar in the video memory in a kernel?* to *OS- How to properly insert text into video memory in a kernel* or something similar to that with the keyword *insert*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you implement this, but I'm sure you have a string buffer in memory some where. What you need to do is move the characters starting at the **end** of the buffer forward by one, then you keep going **backwards**, **until** you reach the cursor's position. Here, you add the new character and increase the cursor's position.

Again, do to the lack of code and information, I can only give you some much help. Here's a little demonstration.

1. `a|bc` The user presses the `b` key.
2. `a|bc` The buffer's memory size is increased by one and the null-terminating character is moved forward first.
3. `a|b c` Followed by `c`.
4. `a| bc` Then `b`.
5. `ab|bc` Now the new character is put into the buffer and the cursor is increased by one.

I hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

The code given still lacks a bit; so I'm going to assume:

- `location`'s indexing returns a `short`.
- `c` and `attribute` are both the size of a `short`, although I'd prefer `chars` to save space.
- `cursor_y` and `cursor_x` are both a `char`.
- The kernel can already move the cursor left and right.

putchar function:

```
short *location = video_memory + (cursor_y*80 + cursor_x);

// If the upper part of the VGA entry isn't zero, then don't write over it!
if (*location & 0xFF00) {
    short *temp = video_memory;
    while (*temp & 0xFF00) temp += 1; // I'm not a fan of -- and ++ operators... Feel free to change them.
    while ((temp+1) != location) {
        *(temp+1) = *temp;
        temp -= 1; // I'm not a fan of -- and ++ operators... Feel free to change them.
    }

*location = c | attribute; // I'm informed that c and attributes are both shorts; although I'd prefer chars.
cursor_x++;
```

**NOTE:** This a *very* crude and <s>untested</s> tested example of how this would work. It may not solve all of your problems, but it does give you a fundamental example.

Comment: i will try to implement it tomorrow as it is late now

Comment: Okay, I'll try to give a _little_ implementation myself.

Comment: The bugs have been vanquished.

Comment: In my code *video_memory is an unsigned short , the cursors are unsigned chars, location and attribute are unsigned shorts

Comment: In that case, you won't need to do a shift for attribute.